# symfony\bundle\frameworkbundle\controller not found

Tags: php, symfony, silex

It seems like it isn't possible to create a form because frameworkbundle is not found. I really don't know how to fix the problem.

I tried to use different methods for creating form and i am using the following link to make this work http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html

```
<?php
namespace Forms;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) 
{
    $builder->add('username', 'username');
    $builder->add('email', 'email');
    $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
        'first_name' => 'password',
        'second_name' => 'confirm',
        'type'      =>  'password',
    ));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => '\Entities\User'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'user';
} 
}
```

This is the form that builds the form and then i have the controller to show the form on the webpage.

```
 <?php
 namespace Controllers;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
 use Forms\UserType;

 class RegisterController extends Controller
 {
public function get(Request $request)
{
    $registration = new UserType();
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $registration, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('account_create'),
    ));
    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $data = $form->getData();
        echo $data;

        return $app->redirect('login');
    }

    return $app['twig']->render('register.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
}
```

Comment: update your vendor, maybe it's broken

Comment: i don't know which libary i need to install in composer.json can you help me out? tried updating but not working

Comment: did `php composer.phar update` (`composer update` in windows) ran without error ?

Comment: yes it finally updated correctly but now i have the following problem Strict standards: Declaration of Controllers\RegisterController:get() should be compatible with that of symfony\Bunndle\Frameworkbundle\Controller\Controller

Comment: there is already a method `get` in parent class `symfony\Bunndle\Frameworkbundle\Controller\Controller` rename your `get` method , and it sould end with the world  `Action` like `registerAction` for example

Comment: one more problem now the following error accur: Registercontroller does not have a constructur so you can't not pass any constructor arguments

Answer (score 2):

Do not actually know if it may fix your problem, but there is an error in your code:

```
$registration = new UserType();
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $registration, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('account_create'),
));
```

You should pass the new `User` object as the second parameter to `$this->createForm` method, but not the form object. See method docs [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_createForm).

You should create your user object & then pass it to `createForm()`:

```
$user = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('account_create'),
));
```